# Printing Extended ASCII characters in Python

Tags: python-3.x, ascii

I'd like to create menu boxes in Python with the following ascii characteres:

ASCII code 200 = ╚ ( Box drawing character double line lower left corner )

ASCII code 201 = ╔ ( Box drawing character double line upper left corner )

ASCII code 202 = ╩ ( Box drawing character double line horizontal and up )

ASCII code 203 = ╦ ( Box drawing character double line horizontal down )

ASCII code 204 = ╠ ( Box drawing character double line vertical and right )

ASCII code 205 = ═ ( Box drawing character double horizontal line )

ASCII code 206 = ╬ ( Box drawing character double line horizontal vertical )

However it seems that these are not supported. When I use chr() the system prints something totally different.

Do you have any advise on how to print the mentioned characters using Python 3?

Thank you.

Comment: None of those are ascii, ascii only goes up to 127, and "extended ascii" doesn't mean anything.

Comment: This may help with your question: https://codescracker.com/python/program/python-program-print-ascii-values.htm

Comment: Have you tried `print('╬')`, etc.?

Comment: May depend on which OS and terminal emulator/shell/command prompt you are using (and what character sets you can get), but on Windows 7 `print('\xc8')` thru `print('\xce')` display those 7 characters for me (`╚` to `╬`)

Comment: @downshift In Python 3?

Comment: @JoshLee, no, unfortunately my comment only works with python2, in python3 it may be possible using string literals `u'\u255a', u'\u2554', u'\u2569', u'\u2566', 
       u'\u2560', u'\u2550', u'\u256c'`. https://repl.it/KjQH

Comment: @JoshLee Actually, "extended ascii" does mean something. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII), as well as [this list](https://www.asciitable.com/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to work with string literals:

```
>>> symbs = [u'\u255a', u'\u2554', u'\u2569', u'\u2566', u'\u2560', u'\u2550', u'\u256c']
>>> for sym in symbs:
...     print(sym)
... 
╚
╔
╩
╦
╠
═
╬
```

This appears to work on all platforms I've tried it on, Windows 7, Mac OS , Linux, etc.

Codes gotten from http://svn.python.org/projects/stackless/trunk/Lib/encodings/cp720.py

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: Actually, in general [Codepage 437](http://svn.python.org/projects/stackless/trunk/Lib/encodings/cp437.py) is a better choice. The codepage you link to is specific for Arabic systems; `437` is the semi-official "original" extended ASCII set.

Comment: It was little troublesome to look for all unicodes in the shared link and pick required ones.
So, for quick look up, here are unicodes for single& double lined box:
`DOUBLE_LEFT_TOP = u'\u2554'   ╔`
`DOUBLE_VERTI_PIPE = u'\u2551'  ║`
`DOUBLE_LEFT_BOTTOM = u'\u255a'  ╚`
`DOUBLE_RIGHT_TOP = u'\u2557'  ╗`
`DOUBLE_RIGHT_BOTTOM = u'\u255d'  ╝`
`DOUBLE_HORIZ_PIPE = u'\u2550'  ═`
`SINGLE_LEFT_TOP = u'\u250c'   ┌`
`SINGLE_VERTI_PIPE = u'\u2502'  │`
`SINGLE_LEFT_BOTTOM = u'\u2514'  └`
`SINGLE_RIGHT_TOP = u'\u2510'  ┐`
`SINGLE_RIGHT_BOTTOM = u'\u2518'  ┘`
`SINGLE_HORIZ_PIPE = u'\u2500'  ─`

Answer (score 3):

Follow-up thanks to Dave Edwards ...

```
class TableBorder:
    def __init__ (self, top_left, top_split, top_right,
        mid_left, mid_split, mid_right,
        low_left, low_split, low_right,
        horizontal, vertical):
        self.top_left = top_left
        self.top_split = top_split
        self.top_right = top_right
        self.mid_left = mid_left
        self.mid_split = mid_split
        self.mid_right = mid_right
        self.low_left = low_left
        self.low_split = low_split
        self.low_right = low_right
        self.horizontal = horizontal
        self.vertical = vertical

Borders0 = TableBorder ('+', '+', '+', '+', '+', '+', '+', '+', '+', '-', '|')
Borders1 = TableBorder (u'\u250c',u'\u252C',u'\u2510',u'\u251C',u'\u253C',u'\u2524',u'\u2514',u'\u2534',u'\u2518',u'\u2500',u'\u2502')
Borders2 = TableBorder (u'\u2554',u'\u2566',u'\u2557',u'\u2560',u'\u256C',u'\u2563',u'\u255a',u'\u2569',u'\u255d',u'\u2550',u'\u2551')

def draw_box (width, height, box):
    span = width-2
    line = box.horizontal * (span)
    print (box.top_left + line + box.top_right)
    body = box.vertical + (' '*span) + box.vertical
    for _ in range (height-1):
        print (body)
    print (box.low_left + line + box.low_right)

draw_box (20, 10, Borders1)
```